# Can I build & run Unity games on PS5 without registering?

Tags: unity, legal, playstation5

So, I have a question on building/running (B&R) Unity games for/on PS5. Specifically, this is only for educational/testing reasons with no intention to sell the games.

Question: **Is it legal to B&R unity games on PS5, without registering or reporting this activity, assuming that I keep these games to myself?**

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Comment: Alright, I have edited the post to include one question.

Comment: https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/212064606-How-do-I-develop-to-PlayStation-platforms- as per the FAQ from Unity regarding PlayStation. I would assume that you are unable to build your project without registering. Though I do not own a PlayStation to test that

Comment: Consider if someone answered this question and said "yes, it's legal", and then you make your game and suddenly find yourself the target of a lawsuit from Sony. Would you want your defense offered in court to be "some pseudonymous stranger on a free website said it was fine"? Or would you perhaps want to get your legal advice from a lawyer, or straight from Sony developer relations instead?

Comment: @Zibelas Since the question focuses on legality, that seems like an answer to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full article about this can be found at https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/212064606-How-do-I-develop-to-PlayStation-platforms-

Considering the passages (emphasis mine)

> If you would like to use Unity to `develop` for PS5 or other
> PlayStation® hardware, you need to be a certified PlayStation®
> developer and have a valid Unity Pro serial key.

and

> To `register` as a PlayStation® Partner, get access to the DevNet
> developer network, and receive your Unity Pro serial key, you first
> need to register on the PlayStation® Partners website.

and

> If you `attempt to build` to a PlayStation platform, you will be faced
> with the following (or similar) message if you do not have a
> PlayStation license activated: `“Your license does not cover PS4 publishing"`.

This implies to me: No. You are not allowed to B&R even if it is for yourself without registering and you will encounter the problem that without registering, you won't even be able to build the game for just your own PlayStation. Trying to circumvent that is against the Eula and might bring you legal trouble.